# Filtering a model by its children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a `Ticket` model which `has_many :tags`. I would like to find all tickets that have tags where `tag.label` is in an array of strings.

Here's what i'm trying at the moment:

```
tags = params[:tags].split(',')
if tags.count > 0 then
  t = t.scoped(include: :tag).where('tags.label' => tags.map(&:label))
end
```

Comment: i've tried this `t = t.scoped(include: :tag).where('tags.label' => tags.map(&:label))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
Ticket.joins(:tags).where(:tags => { :label => array_of_strings })
```

Or as a scope:

```
scope :by_labels, lambda { |tags| joins(:tags).where(:tags => { :label => tags }) unless tags.blank? }
```

The problem with Mikhail Nikalyukin's solution is `.map(&:label)`. That part is not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Try this scope

```
scope :by_labels, lambda{ |tags| joins(:tags).where('tags.label IN (?)',tags) unless tags.blank? }
```